# Extracting email addresses and names from a text file

Tags: c#, email, text

I will try to explain the problem as good as I can. I have a text file with email addresses and names. It looks like this:  `Barb Beney "de.mariof@vienna.aa", "Beny Beney" bet@catering.at`,etc....all in the same line. This is just an example and I have like thousands of such data in one big text file. I want to extract the emails and names so that I get something like this in the end:

Beny Beney bet@catering.at - separate, next to each other, in one line and without quote marks. And in the end it should eliminate all duplicate addresses from the file.

I wrote the code for extracting email addresses and it works, but I don't know how to do the rest. How to extract the names put it in one line as the addresses and eliminate duplicates. I hope I described it properly so you know what I'm trying to do. This is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace Email
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtractEmails(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\New.txt", @"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\Email.txt");   
    }


    public static void ExtractEmails(string inFilePath, string outFilePath)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(inFilePath);

        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


        MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);


        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(emailMatch.Value);

        }

        File.WriteAllText(outFilePath, sb.ToString());
    }
```

}
}

Comment: email address and names are separated uisng what ?

Comment: the original file looks like "FirstName LastName" <Emailadress>, 2nd, 3rd....they are separated with spaces. And the end result should look like: FistName LastName Emailadress - in one line without quote marks, then second line etc...

Comment: i think its better to split all of your date using string.split(',') and put the result into an array ,now you  have all email and names indexed in an array,then split each index using string.split(' ')[split using space] and now you have firstName ,lastName and email address in some specific indexs

Comment: So the email is enclosed in quotes or the name? Or both? Or either?

Comment: Just put an exact entry instead of trying to explain what format they're in

Comment: @ako: Splitting on space is decidedly dodgy. Sure it would work with "John Smith", but it will immediately blow up when it meets a "John van SomethingOrOther" or similar.

Comment: You could create a generic list and add the matches to that instead of using StringBuilder. Then you can filter out dupes easier that way. You can then do your splitting up of the names and emails in a foreach loop on the list. `List<string> emailMatches = new List<string>();`

Comment: @ako yeah but i don't know if a name has 1,2,3,4 words...if it's firstName, MiddleName, Secondname...

Comment: Is there a way to say exctract all NotEmails from text, get rid of the quote marks (if theres any) and put it in one file(like using another Regex)? or like not emailRegex? I've tried negating regex but i was unsuccesful....

Comment: i think it does not matter how many parts a name have ,at last the full name is inside a (" " ) then when splitting using (space) you can get the  name easily

Comment: @ako not all names are inside (" "), some are and some aren't. Some names are in brackets. That's why I can't use Split,because i don't know where to split.....That's why it should go like: take all text before the email (Regex) pattern occures, put it in one line and filter out all quotes and brackets. I tried negating the whole EmailRegex pattern but it doesnt work.....probably i don't know how to write it....

Answer (score 0):

Welcome you can use this code and it will work on file made by creating new file which will contain all e-mails without duplicates:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter w = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\NonDuplicateEmails.txt");
        ExtractEmails(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\New.txt", @"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\Email.txt");
        TextReader r = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\Email.txt");
        RemovingAllDupes(r, w);
    }

    public static void RemovingAllDupes(TextReader reader, TextWriter writer)
    {
        string currentLine;
        HashSet<string> previousLines = new HashSet<string>();

        while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Add returns true if it was actually added,
            // false if it was already there
            if (previousLines.Add(currentLine))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(currentLine);
            }
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: "_it will work in the correct way_" - What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

For the new desired formatting, you could do something like this:

```
private string[] parseEmails(string bigStringiIn){

string[] output;
string bigString;

bigString = bigStringiIn.Replace("\"", "");

output = bigString.Slit(",".ToCharArray());

return output;
}
```

it takes the string with the mail adresses, replaces the quote marks, then splits the string into a string array with the format: `name lastname email@some.com`

for the duplicated entries deletion, a nested for should do the trick, checking (maybe after a .Split()) for matching strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this code with big files:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtractEmails(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\New.txt", @"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\Email.txt");
        var sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\Email.txt"));
        var sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Users\drake\Desktop\NonDuplicateEmails.txt"));
        RemovingAllDupes(sr, sw);
    }

    public static void RemovingAllDupes(StreamReader str, StreamWriter stw)
    {

        var lines = new HashSet<int>();
        while (!str.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = str.ReadLine();
            int hc = line.GetHashCode();
            if (lines.Contains(hc))
                continue;

            lines.Add(hc);
            stw.WriteLine(line);
        }
        stw.Flush();
        stw.Close();
        str.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you. I just have to figure out how to extract the name and email to one line, removing " and (). I can't use split because the Name can be 2-5 words. If i have it like this FirstName "SecondName" ThirdName <Emailaddress>, in the end it should be the Names without quotes and brackets and Email in one line saved to one file....